# How to delete columns with regular expression for the header in R

Tags: regex, r

In R, I'd like to delete all the columns of my matrix which header contains a certain word.
When I know exactly the name of the header I use `y=x[,!colnames(x)=='time']` but here I'd need to use a regular expression to delete all the columns containing 'dummy'. I had seen that I could use '+' after the pattern but `y=x[,!colnames(x)=='dummy'+]` or `y=x[,!colnames(x)==dummy+]` give error (knowing that 'dummy' is not the begining/end of the column's name).
Thank you !

Comment: @akrun I think `invert=TRUE` or `!grepl(...)` might be safer than negative indexing (haven't tried it but have a feeling that bad things happen if the string is not matched ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example would be nice but I think that e.g.

```
y <- x[,!grepl("dummy+",colnames(x))]
```

should work.  If you have `"dummy"` stored in a variable, use `paste0(begstr,"+")` to construct the regular expression.